# How many candies can a villager eat before moving slower than guards?

Tags: nintendo-land

In the Animal Crossing guards vs. villagers game, exactly how many candies can a single villager eat before they move more slowly than the guards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friends and I experimented. After eating 10 candies, a villager is either the same speed as or just slightly slower than the guards.

Comment: This was specifically in a 4 vs 1 game. I'm not sure whether it's different with different numbers of players.